# Android Fatality from Seemingly Sound Method

Tags: java, android, exception

I am working on a simple android project but have encountered a dreaded FATAL EXCEPTION, and don't really have the know-how to determine if I am doing something off limits in the world of Android...
 I have this code:

```
private OnClickListener butonList_start = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Good Luck.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        otherBtn_1.setOnClickListener(otherListener_1);
        otherBtn_2.setOnClickListener(otherListener_2);

        aTextView.setTextSize(30);
        aTextView.setText("");
        aTextView.setMaxLines(1);
    }
};
```

All of this executes without a hitch, until at the very end I enter this:

```
activate();
```

Which is a reference to this code:

```
private void activate(){
    setImage_AS();
    first = selector1_AS();
    second = selector2_AS();
    aTextView_2.setText(first);
    aTextView_3.setText(second);

}

private void setImage_AS(){
    int xxx = randm.nextInt(2);
    if(xxx==0){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.crew_31242514);
        int op = 0;
    }
    if(xxx==1){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int op = 1;
    }
}


private int selector1_AS(){
    return randm.nextInt(50);
}
private int selector2_AS(){
    return randm.nextInt(first);
}
```

Through the method "activate" I set the image of a pre-defined ImageView, and give both 'first' and 'second' value through their respective methods which randomly assign values within those parameters.

Now, nothing else happens after this unless a user presses a button, so, the error should be in here right? What am I doing wrong, I've looked over this so much but can't get any hints from the LogCat which just returns FATAL EXCEPTION and no details (unless I cannot see them).

My code has no errors and therefore no references to objects or types that haven't been declared, and everything runs smoothly in the app until the button that activates butonList_start is clicked. Please help me!

Here're the LogCat lines
[image]

**FOUND THE ISSUE**
*Still a tad Confused*

The issue was a product of my attempts to set the text of the TextView to the value given by 'first' or 'second', which was an int... But why would that be a problem, will setText() only accept Strings?

Comment: Please post the logcat lines including and after the FATAL_EXCEPTION. That should have the stack trace which will tell you what exception was thrown and what line of your code triggered it. You can use the "adb logcat" command in your terminal and scroll to area with the exception and copy and paste it.

Comment: There's nothing obvious from what you've posted, though the resource names would be the first things I'd check. I think we need a little more code so that we can run/test this. I assume you have LogCat set to Verbose mode.

Comment: I  may not, how can I check? Nevermind, got it, it is.

Comment: I guess it looks like a resource issue then, I'll check on that

Comment: I assume randm is an instance of the Random class. Do you initialize it anywhere? Random randm=new Random();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at line 63 of Basic.java in your activate() method.  You are trying to set the text of a text view to an int.  I would guess it is the line `aTextView_2.setText(first);`.

So, TextView has a method [setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) that expect that int to be a string resource id.  There is no string resource that matches the id you have  given it and so the exception is thrown.

If you want to display an integer's value in a TextView try using something like `myTextView.setText( String.valueOf( someInteger ) );` instead.  This method, [setText(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), takes a CharSequence and will allow you to directly specify the text you want to be displayed in the TextView

Comment: Nice one, @David Mays! I was unaware of the setText(int resId) method.